# S3 put events not triggering lambda under load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am developing a serverless application and for part of that I am triggering a lambda on S3 Put events. But when I tried to run the lambda under load 10-20 rps, I see, the lamda invocations count is very less than the PUT events count. I am not very much sure how to debug and identify the cause of the failure. 
Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Are most of the PUT requests hitting the same object key?

Comment: To quote the docs: Amazon S3 event notifications are designed to be delivered at least once. Typically, event notifications are delivered in seconds but can sometimes take a minute or longer. If two writes are made to a single non-versioned object at the same time, it is possible that only a single event notification will be sent.

Comment: @jellycsc -No every time a new object key is created, will have to see if somehow object key is duplicated but the chances seems to be very rare.

Comment: @jarmod - I am investigating the same, if two writes are made to single non-versioned object at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

enter image description hereYou can go to the lambda function and form there to **monitoring**.
Then go to **View Logs In CloudWatch**.
Click on the **logs** it will have the information to debug your webapp.

[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U92Qt.png)

[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55GY8.png)